# My SQL database name does not match my wp-config name

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I am having strange connection errors on my Wordpress site. I am not too knowledgeable but since I have moved from one hosting to another, my site displays these weird errors. Again, I have noticed the server name in my wp-config.php file is different from MySQL database name? Could this be the problem?

Here are the errors:

```
Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/.....and line 118

Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home./(servername)/public_html/wp-content/themes/clip/header.php on line 118
```

Comment: _“Again, I have noticed the server name in my wpconfig file is different from mysql database name? Could ths be the problem?”_ – rather not. Those _are_ two different things, so it is to be expected that they are named differently as well. // According to the warning, it tried to make a connection without any user name or password - so likely you did not update the configuration file correctly.

Comment: Great, briefly how do I update it?

Comment: Have you sought support help from your new hosting provider? Have you looked at the file called `wp_config.php` in your new WordPress instance? That file contains parameters called `DB_HOST`, `DB_USER`, `DB_PASSWORD`, and `DB_NAME`, which must be set to match your new MySQL db instance. You can edit that file.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have seen those parameters. Will be on it